# How do I connect to database in ASP.NET Core Web API without using EF?

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-core

I am attempting to create an ASP.NET Core Web API without using EF Core. Instead, I would like to use System.Data.SQLClient to connect to SQL server, and query it using plain old SQL. That said, I'm having a bit of trouble figuring out how to establish the connection. I've found a lot of tutorials online that address how to do this with EF. But, I'm a bit perplexed as to how it's done without it.

Answer (score 6):

You do it exactly the same way as you would in any .net application:

```
using (var conn = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection(connectionString)) {
    conn.Open();
    using (var cmd = conn.CreateCommand()) {
        cmd.CommandText = "SELECT 'hello world'";
        using (var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader()) {
            while (reader.Read()) {
                ...
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You will find that some parts of asp.net core require EF, like the identity claims stuff, so you will need to handle your own authentication and won't be able to use their security attributes and the like.  I've gone this route on several asp.net core projects with no regrets

Comment: Thanks for the response, Tim. I was moreso referring to how I go about integrating that with the Web API framework. I noted that there is a Configure method in Startup.cs, but it seems to rely heavily on dependency injection, and this is where I'm struggling. My apologies for the confusion, I should have been more clear that the question had two parts.

Comment: Are you asking how to build and add a service to DI that would be a factory for SqlConnection objects to try and match the DI pattern of asp.net core?  What specifically isn't working for you?

Comment: My issue is that I have an existing database that I simply want to query, and push a result to a REST API. My understanding from the tutorials is that I am expected to initiate the DB connection in the `ConfigureServices` method in `Startup.cs` and then execute my commands in a controller class. Am I misunderstanding how this paradigm has been designed?

Comment: Make sure you are using the latest version of dotnet core or the sqlclient wouldn't be available

Comment: The analog is would be to load your connection string in ConfigureServices, write your own service that implements an interface that creates a SqlConnection object based on that connection string, and have your controller method get a reference to that service via DI and use it to creat SqlConnections without having to be aware of the connection string... but you don't *have* to do it that way

Comment: Wow. I must admit that a lot of that went over my head. I'm still wrapping my head around DI in C# (as I'm new to the language). I managed to get it working by simply putting all of the database connection info into one of the annotated controller methods. But, this feels like the wrong way to do it. I'm effectively establishing a new connection every time the endpoint is hit. Is that how it's supposed to work?

Comment: Yes, you should be creating a connection only when you need it (e.g. in the controller action method) and disposing it as soon as you are done-- and allowing connection pooling to reuse connections as it sees fit.  *HOW* you accomplish that can be a lot cleaner using DI and a connection factory pattern, but at the end of the day,as long as you have a unified way of creating connections it doesn't really matter.

Answer (score 0):

You must use SqlConnection and SqlCommand classes. From the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
private static void CreateCommand(string queryString, string connectionString)
{
    using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(
           connectionString))
    {
        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(queryString, connection);
        command.Connection.Open();
        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}

CreateCommand("insert into...", "[your connection string]");
```

Aditionally, [Dapper](https://github.com/StackExchange/Dapper) is a good option for accessing data, is an object mapper that extends IDbConnection, so you don't have to worry about object creation. From dapper's docummentation

```
public class Dog
{
    public int? Age { get; set; }
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public float? Weight { get; set; }

    public int IgnoredProperty { get { return 1; } }
}            

var guid = Guid.NewGuid();
var dog = connection.Query<Dog>("select Age = @Age, Id = @Id", new { Age = (int?)null, Id = guid });
```